# Changing the From Address with the Printer, email, and PDF versions module

Tags: 7, emails

I'm using the [Printer, email, and PDF versions](https://www.drupal.org/project/print) module. On all my 'resource' nodes (resource content type) I have a link now that says 'Send by Email'. Great. But when it sends the email it's sending it with a'from' address as MY email (the site admin). I'd rather it be the email of the person who's sending the resource. There is an email field on that form they have to fill out to send the resource to someone else.

Anyone know how to make the email they use for THEIR email in the form be the 'from' email to whomever they are sending this resource?

Answer (score 0):

It's in **Administration » Configuration » User interface » Printer, email and PDF versions**, as the **Use Reply-To Header** option.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I had that checked already. The problem is that I want to enable this feature for anonymous users, not just logged in users.

Comment: Have you granted anons permission to **Access the Send by email functionality**?

Comment: yes, I have. They can send the email fine, it just always shows as coming from me, the drupal admin. I'm wondering if maybe there's a way to alter it programmatically with a hook or something.

Comment: Hmm, are you on shared hosting or some environment where outgoing email might be restricted? The toggling Reply-To... allows me to send out emails as name@example.com.

Comment: Yes, I am on shared hosting. You can just specify an email right there in the config page? Hmmm...any idea how to fix that with shared hosting? I would think the option would still appear though...Drupal doesn't know I have shared hosting. Am I totally wrong for thinking that?

Comment: Correct. Drupal is going to set the correct headers and pass it along to whatever MTA PHP is configured for. I'm not 100% sure that's the problem, I'm just trying reason why we see different behavior. If you have the core contact module enabled, you can test that form out to see if it sends out email as name@example.com when you fill it in the form.

Comment: Ok, so I enabled that and set the recipient to my work email and then filled out the form as an anonymous user (after config permissions of course) and set my name to my name to bubba fett and his email, I then clicked send I received the message in my work email as expected coming from bubba fett. So I don't think it's my hosting provider.